# iis not found, even if it shows as installed

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

I need iis for asp.net web apps. I am using Windows 7 Home Basic,SP1.
In services iis web admin is started. When i run inetmgr.exe in run, it shows inetmmgr     not found. In control panel ->on/off features-> i have checked   iis boxes. But when i try to run inetmgr.msi it shows "to start iis management console from turn on/off features", but when i checked there iis management console is not shown under ii6 management compatibility.

When i try to install iis7 express it shows "higher version is already installed".
When i try to install iis8 it goes into repair and shows some error.

Also in browser for localhost:80/ it shows "the file extension for the requested URL does not have a handler configured to process the  request on the Web server".

What is the problem?How come iis6, iis7 and iis8 are installed?
Please help me out, i am new to iis. 
Thanks a lot.

Apache web server is also running on localhost:8080. Does this create a problem.

Answer (score 0):

IIS is not available on Windows 7 Home edition, Microsoft said the Home edition is not meant for networking. So upgrading to professional or ultimate editions will help.

Check out [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=abc59783-89de-4adc-b770-0a720bb21deb)

Comment: okay, i didnt know that. But i do have apache running, then can i use apache instead of iis for asp.net wep apps?

Comment: Don't have much knowledge about that but it should definitely work. Also try reading through this [Installing IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Home Premium, Home Basic, or Home Starter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731911.aspx)

Comment: also if iis express is there, the os does not matter, it provides all the features for iis to work. is it right?

Comment: Precisely. The version of windows shouldn't matter